# How to access Google Calendar API using Google+ sign-in button?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-plus, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

This is the first time I ask a question here, so I'm sorry if I write the question in wrong format. So I've implemented Google+ sign-in button in my Android app (using Eclipse) like in this link: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in, but I don't understand how to use that for accessing Google Calendar API. Here's a reference of what I'm trying to implement: https://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html . I understand the concept, but when I tried to use that, nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
public class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    Activity mActivity;
    String mScope;
    String mEmail;
    String mToken;

    GetTask(Activity activity, String name, String scope) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mScope = scope;
        this.mEmail = name;
    }

    /**
     * Executes the asynchronous job. This runs when you call execute()
     * on the AsyncTask instance.
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String mToken = fetchToken();
            if (mToken != null) {
                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(mToken);
                HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
                JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
                calGoogle = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).
                            setApplicationName("Calendar View").build();
                Log.d("Token", mToken);

                // Create and initialize a new event
                Event event = new Event();
                event.setSummary("Appointment");
                event.setLocation("Somewhere");

                ArrayList<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
                attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("attendeeEmail"));
                event.setAttendees(attendees);

                Date startDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
                DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
                DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));

                // Insert the new event
                Event createdEvent = calGoogle.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // The fetchToken() method handles Google-specific exceptions,
            // so this indicates something went wrong at a higher level.
            // TIP: Check for network connectivity before starting the AsyncTask.

        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets an authentication token from Google and handles any
     * GoogleAuthException that may occur.
     */
    protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
        try {
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
            // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present
            // so we need to show the user some UI in the activity to recover.
            //mActivity.handleException(userRecoverableException);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
            // Some other type of unrecoverable exception has occurred.
            // Report and log the error as appropriate for your app.

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to add event to Google Calendar, but it didn't do anything. I've checked LogCat, but it looks pretty normal to me. My question is, how can we use Google APIs using Google+ sign-in button instead of oauth2.0? Google recommends that for Android apps, but I don't understand the explanation.

Comment: Did you paste the SHA-1 fingerprint into the Signing certificate fingerprint field? Check this link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

Comment: hi @Bojan, did you solve that?